# How to create sql connection string for remote access

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql database on a desktop computer &  that computer is connected to a LAN .The LAN has an internet connection via 4G router which is having a static ip.

Now I want to connect to that sql server via internet.How can I create the connection string ,

Connection string for Local computer would be as follows ,

```
Data Source=Asanka_Mahesh.\\sqlexpress,1433;Initial Catalog=Project_Monitoring;Integrated Security=False ; User ID = Mahesh_KENT ; Password = 1987@
```

Comment: You can't. It has nothing to do with the conenction string. Which, by the way, isn't local-only. It *does* contain the name of the machine. You could replace the name with an IP address or FQDN. *THE ROUTER* won't allow external connections. Which is a good thing by the way, otherwise you'd get hacked within 30 seconds if you exposed *anything* to the public internet without firewalls, hardening and encrypted connections. Most Telcos block incoming connections and VPN anyway to force you to buy business connection contracts.

Comment: For example, how are you going to *log into* that server? Are you going to transmit the username/password unencrypted? You'd have to enable SSL encryption on the server, which means installing certificates.